# How big is the stackoverflow database?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, database

How many gigabytes is the StackOverflow database file (SQLServer I'm guessing?)

Comment: Correct; it is SQL Server.

Comment: `too localized`? Oops, did my comment make the database grow again?

Comment: Yes, too localized since the answer is always changing. What if we find out the average amount of space per question? Then the size can be estimated in the future (at least short-term).

Comment: It depends on how you measure. The XMLs have a size, and the binary database files have another.

Answer (score 10):

For a more up to date answer, thousands of gigabytes. https://stackexchange.com/performance has more info.

Comment: I’d phrase this as “a couple of terabytes” (or “a few terabytes” if we want to discuss all of SE rather than just SO as in the question) rather than “thousands of gigabytes”.

Answer (score 6):

Let me guess also, 6 to 8 <strike>weeks</strike> Gigs

Comment: If you count the whole trilogy, you are not too off the mark.

Comment: @jjnguy: too subtle?

Comment: @json I just wanted the joke to reach a wider audience.  Not everyone sees a 6 followed by an 8 and gets the joke. (Even though they should)